# Find all functions with second argument by Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a function named `test_function` in my PHP project. Called it many times. I want to find all `test_function` that have the second argument. like:

```
test_function('something',true);
//or
test_function('something',false);
//or
test_function('something',true,true);
//or
test_function(another_function('anotherthing',true),true);
```

Don't want to find this:

```
test_function('something');
```

I'm using Eclipse search with regular expression enabled. using this:

```
test_function[(].+[,].+[)]
```

but it will search something I don't want. like this:

```
test_function('something').another_function(something,true);
//or
test_function(another_function('anotherthing',true));
```

the 2nd argument is `true` or `false`. I also did this regex but the problem still exists:

```
test_function[(].+[,](true|false).+[)]
```

How can I write Regex for this search?

Comment: Try `test_function\('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'\s*,`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew found nothing.

Comment: [This pattern above matches the texts](https://regex101.com/r/SJCbo8/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. yeah, It works there but I don't know why it doesn't work on Eclipse regex search. It's weird.

Comment: Try a negating approach - [`test_function\((?!'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'\))`](https://regex101.com/r/iVZDV5/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now this one works on eclipse. but still finds `test_function(another_function('anotherthing',true));`. please send the answer. so I can accept that.

Comment: Does it mean there can be only one nested function? See https://regex101.com/r/iVZDV5/2. As a [one-liner expression](https://regex101.com/r/iVZDV5/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, this one fixed all of my problems. Please send it as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to only want to match the occurrences of a `test_function` that contains at least 2 arguments, the first argument being either a single-quoted PHP string literal or a nested function with a string literal as the first argment, and optional `true` or `false` further arguments.

That means you may solve the problem using a regex in Eclipse since you do not need to match arbitrary recursion levels. Use

```
test_function\((?!\w+\('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'(?:,(?:true|false))*\)\)|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iVZDV5/3)

**Details**

- `test_function\(` - a literal text `test_function(`
- `(?!` - start of a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is...
- `\w+\('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'(?:,(?:true|false))*\)\)` - a sequence of chars:

  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (a method name)
  - `\('` - a `('` subnstring
  - `[^'\\]*` - zero or more chars othert than `\` and `'`
  - `(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of any escape sequences (`\\.` matches `\` and any char after it) followed with zero or more chars othert than `\` and `'`
  - `'` - a single quote
  - `(?:,(?:true|false))*` - 0+ sequences of a `,` and `true` or `false` values after it
  - `\)\)` - a `))` substring
- `|` - or
- `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'\)` - a single quoted string literal and `)` after it
- `)` - end of the lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first parameter cannot contain a ")" you can use

```
test_function[(][^)]+[,][^)]+[)]
```

If parenthesises are possible you will have to look for pairs of them, which gets to the borders of what can be done with regexes. I.e. it is possible but ugly.
Provide more sample input if you want help with that.

Comment: Didn't work. finds nothing. the 2nd or 3rd parameter is simply true or false. I added another regex that i tried. It has the same problem :(

Comment: Once a string literal contains a `)`, this [will stop working](https://regex101.com/r/SJCbo8/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True, I comment on that possibility and how to go about it.

Comment: Yeah, that comment is wrong. Because matching balanced parentheses won't help here to match a string literal, cf. `test_function("Some ) and (text)", true)`.

Comment: That is why I said "close to borders" and asked for more sample input if help is needed.

Comment: Here is the syntax of [PHP string literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and @Yunnosch I updated the question. I found many things like `test_function(another_function('anotherthing',true))` or `test_function(another_function('anotherthing',true).' '.another_function('anotherthing'...))`

Comment: Ah yes, that is what we were afraid of. Sorry my answer as is is restricted to paren-free. Witkors comment contains a string-syntax based solution, very nice. Try to find out why that does not work. That needs to be clarified before entering higher regex art territory.

Comment: Can you restrict to one or more, but non-nested pairs? I.e. "()()" but not "(())".